# Elasticsearch: Filtering by Date and Article Category

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going through an Elasticsearch tutorial, and I had something pop into my mind. What if I want to filter based on two different attributes at the same time? I have this query about searching for articles about Donald Trump from recent news articles:

```
GET news_headlines/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
        "match_phrase": {
          "headline": "Donald Trump"
          }
         }
        ],
       "filter":{
          "range":{
             "date": {
               "gte": "2014-03-25",
               "lte": "2016-03-25"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding something within the `filter` section to exclude articles with `category` equal to `POLITICS`, but I received an error. What would be the best way to syntactically incorporate that into my `filter` section? Thanks in advance... I am a noob at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need `must_not`. It will exclude the docs matching the query.

Assuming you have a keyword field for category:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
        "match_phrase": {
          "headline": "Donald Trump"
          }
         }
        ],
       "filter":{
          "range":{
             "date": {
               "gte": "2014-03-25",
               "lte": "2016-03-25"
          }
        }
      },
"must_not" : [
{
          "term":{
             "category": {
               "value": "POLITICS",
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```